# What is the default behaviour of a controller action not marked with AcceptVerbs, HttpGet or HttpPost?

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-2, http-post, http-get, acceptverbs

If I create a controller action and do not decorate it with `AcceptVerbs`, `HttpPost` or `HttpGet`. What is the default behaviour?

Does the action allow any access method or does it default to *GET*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's accessible via any verb.

Comment: @marcind tested it and it works like you answered. It would be great to have some links to official documentation that states this.

Answer (score 4):

### In Web API 2.1:

it depends on the name of the action. If the action starts with "Get*" then it will default to only accept GET requests. If it starts with "Put*" then it will default to only accept PUT requests. Same with POST.

If it doesn't start with any known verb then it will default to only accept POST.

Here are the results of my testing:

```
public class BlahController : ApiController
{
    // only allows GET
    public string GetSomething() { return "GetSomething blah"; }

    // only allows PUT
    public string PutSomething() { return "PutSomething blah"; }

    // only allows POST
    public string PostSomething() { return "PostSomething blah"; }

    // only allows POST
    public string Fleabag() { return "Fleabag blah"; }
}
```

Comment: It's quite strange, because I have just received: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'" for an action without attributes (tested in WebApi 2.2).

Comment: Try to test it with an action method distinct from "Get()" or "Post()" or "GetById()", because in these cases, if there is no Accepted verb attribute, the http method will be resolved automatically from the name.

Comment: Contrary to my answer, AFAICT if the method name starts with "Get" then it will default to only accept GET requests. Otherwise it defaults to accept any verb.

Comment: I've tested with Dummy() action/method and it's only accepting POST. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Freerider it depends on the name of the action method, see my edit for details.

Comment: Hmm I'm gonna do some more checks, something not right.

Comment: There was a bug in my testing causing me to misunderstand how it works. I updated my edited answer once more, pretty sure it's nailed now.

Comment: I've reached the same conclusion. It would be nice to have an offical documentation with this info.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:asp.net-mvc-2], Web API is an entirely different beast. While similar to MVC routing, it does behave differently for certain things.

Comment: @Stijn I updated my answer to make it clearer that I was talking about WebAPI and not MVC.